# how to get user email with python social auth with facebook and save it

Tags: python, django, facebook, python-social-auth

I'm trying to implement [python-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth) in django.

I want users to authenticate through facebook and save their email.

I'm able to authenticate users but the extended permission for email is not showing up in the facebook authentification box and it's not storing the email in the database.

In settings.py I have the follwoing:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY='xxx'
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET='xxx'
FACEBOOK_EXTENDED_PERMISSIONS = ['email']

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',
    'social.backends.email.EmailAuth',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

LOGIN_URL = '/login/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/done/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
URL_PATH = ''
SOCIAL_AUTH_STRATEGY = 'social.strategies.django_strategy.DjangoStrategy'
SOCIAL_AUTH_STORAGE = 'social.apps.django_app.default.models.DjangoStorage'

SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'social.pipeline.user.get_username',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_by_email',
    # 'users.pipeline.require_email',
    'social.pipeline.mail.mail_validation',
    'social.pipeline.user.create_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
    'social.pipeline.user.user_details'
)
```

The facebook dialog box...

[image]

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

After some changes in Facebook Login API - Facebook's Graph API v2.4
You will have to add these lines to fetch email

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE = ['email']
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_PROFILE_EXTRA_PARAMS = {
    'fields': 'id,name,email', 
}
```

Comment: Yep.. You need the EXTRA_PARAMS also

Comment: Perfect, this updates users in my db when they log back in.

Comment: Does this still work? I can't get it working and the worst thing is that it doesn't even produce any error logs, it just silently skips the email retrieval step.

Comment: Email not being retrieve not even with this setting

Answer (score 14):

I think the problem is using FACEBOOK_EXTENDED_PERMISSIONS.

According to http://python-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/backends/facebook.html#oauth2 you should use:

`SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE = ['email']`

Comment: Does it still work by any chance? I can't get it working.

Comment: You need the EXTRA_PARAMS also. See answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your settings.py file

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE = ['email']
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing it on the test website?

Re-read the documentation please: [https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/facebook.html#oauth2][1]

It says:

> If you define a redirect URL in Facebook setup page, be sure to not define http://127.0.0.1:8000 or http://localhost:8000 because it won’t work when testing